# Memory leak into integer C++

Tags: c++, arduino

i've added a new function to my code and now an integer i used gets affected by some sort of memory overrun. (Note that this is concerning a .ino Sketch for an Arduino Uno)

Instead of decrementing by 1 with `xPos--;` it decrements by 256
(If i remove the printText function the overrun doesn't happen).

The integer xPos and the char buffer are defined with

```
int xPos = 0;
char buffer[26];
```

just under the includes. the u8g.drawStr function draws the string on my display and takes two ints for x and y and a char* as the string as arguments.

```
void printText(const char* inputText)
{
    int y = yPos;
    for (int i = strlen(inputText); i > 0; i -= 25)
    {
        strncpy(buffer, &inputText[strlen(inputText) - i], i >= 25 ? 25 : i);
        buffer[26] = '\0';
        u8g.drawStr(0, y, buffer);
        y += 8;
    }
}
```

Any council would be very appreciated :)

Comment: `buffer[26] = '\0';` is a buffer overflow; size 26 means the valid indices are 0 through to 25

Comment: Also you can just use `25` as the argument to `strncpy`, because it will stop reading the input when it hits the null terminator

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it, damn i was blind.

Comment: Yeah i did that before, the whole `i >= 25 ? 25 : i` thing was just me trying to fix it :D

Comment: You really seem to love computing `strlen`. A lot.

Comment: Since the code already calls `strlen`, there's no need for that `strncpy` dance. You know how big the input string is.

Comment: I didn't really worry about performance since i just wanted to get it working somehow. But thanks for pointing it out, i'll change it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your buffer has only 26 slots:

```
    char buffer[26];
```

Yet you try to write to its 27th slot:

```
    buffer[26] = '\0';
```

That's not going to work. (Zero is the first slot, one is the second slot, and so on. So 26 is the 27th slot.)

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it :)